# PHP alternative way of writing stdClass

Tags: php, stdclass

When doing stdClass in PHP we can do it this way:

```
// Create new stdClass Object
$init = new stdClass;

// Add some test data
$init->foo = "Test data";
$init->bar = new stdClass;
$init->bar->baaz = "Testing";
$init->bar->fooz = new stdClass;
$init->bar->fooz->baz = "Testing again";
$init->foox = "Just test";
```

Is there any other alternative way to do with so that it looks cleaner like we can do with JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$array  = array('x'=>123);
$object = (object) $array;
```